# Find max value and Drop row based on time python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, sum

I am trying to find the maximum value of precip based on the station column and the hour of the valid column. I have no workable code as I've been trying this forever and have found no even close to working solution.

Here is the dataframe I am working with

| station | valid | precip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1V4 | 2022-02-23 07:54:00 | 0.2 |
| 1V4 | 2022-02-23 07:55:00 | 0.2 |
| 1V4 | 2022-02-23 07:58:00 | 0.4 |
| 1V4 | 2022-02-23 08:07:00 | 0.1 |
| 1V4 | 2022-02-23 08:51:00 | 0.6 |
| BTV | 2022-02-23 07:52:00 | 0.1 |
| BTV | 2022-02-23 07:54:00 | 0.2 |
| BTV | 2022-02-23 07:59:00 | 0.3 |
| BTV | 2022-02-23 08:02:00 | 0.0 |
| BTV | 2022-02-23 08:16:00 | 0.0 |
| BTV | 2022-02-23 08:29:00 | 0.3 |

This is what I want it to look like

| station | valid | precip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1V4 | 2022-02-23 07:58:00 | 0.4 |
| 1V4 | 2022-02-23 08:51:00 | 0.6 |
| BTV | 2022-02-23 07:59:00 | 0.3 |
| BTV | 2022-02-23 08:29:00 | 0.3 |

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by station and hour and get the `idxmax`, then slice:

```
df['valid'] = pd.to_datetime(df['valid'])

df.loc[df.groupby(['station', df['valid'].dt.hour])['precip'].idxmax()]
```

output:

```
   station               valid  precip
2      1V4 2022-02-23 07:58:00     0.4
4      1V4 2022-02-23 08:51:00     0.6
7      BTV 2022-02-23 07:59:00     0.3
10     BTV 2022-02-23 08:29:00     0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to group by the hour and the station

```
df1['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['valid'], infer_datetime_format=True).dt.hour
df1['precip_max'] = df1.groupby(['station', 'Hour'])['precip'].transform('max')
df1.loc[df['precip'] == df['precip_max']]
```